# Sqrt of a floating point number

Tags: c

Write a C program that asks the user to enter a floating point number from the keyboard and then prints out the square root of that number is the question. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
double x, result;
printf("Enter a positive number.\n");
scanf("&f", &x);
result = sqrt(x);
printf("The square root of %f is %f.\n", x, result); 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&f` is not a `scanf` format code...

Comment: `scanf("&f", &x);` --> `if (scanf("%lf", &x) != 1) Handle_Error()`;  % not &, lf, not f, check result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unary '&' operator delivers the reference (to the operand variable's memory address), while the '%' operator in the context of a scanf or printf, for instance, in conjunction with a particular ANSI C symbols for variable type, such as 'lf' for type double, is known as a *format specifier*.  By placing an integer value between the two, as in '%2lf', one can specify the precision to be read or printed.  %f specifies a float type variable, and this achieves lower precision than a double.  See the docs too.  By the way, in C++, precision is specified otherwise.

So:

```
double x, result;
printf("Enter a positive number.\n");
scanf("%f", &x); //<--- use %lf (for 'long float' ) instead of &f
```

Comment: @Brian Graham, there's no link in my answer.

Comment: There was no other view option that said "code only answer". Explain what your code does so readers can understand.

Comment: @BrianGraham, okay, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
scanf("%lf",&x);
```

instead of

```
scanf("&f", &x);
```

Comment: `"%f"` is for scanning a `float`, not a `double` -- needs to be `"%lf"`

Comment: yes, agree with @Dmitri 
Use 
scanf("%lf", &x);
printf("The square root of %lf is %lf.\n", x, result);